# How to aggregate by 2 conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a table like below

| date | train | condition 1 | condition 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day1 | 1111 | true | 0 |
| day2 | 2222 | false | 2 |

.....

I want to group the train with date,

| date | train total count | train with condition 1 is true | train with condition 2 > 0 | train with condition 1 true and condition 2>0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| day1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| day2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I wrote a function like below and find it seems not able to support unhashable type: 'list'?

```
df1 = (
    df.groupby('date')
        .agg(**{
        'train total count': ('train', 'count'),
        'train condition1 count': ('conditon1', lambda x: sum(x.gt(0))),
        'train condition1 &2 count': (['condition1', 'condition2'], lambda x: sum(x[0] + x[1] > 0))
    }).reset_index()
)
```

Comment: You can't used named aggregation with 2 columns like that `(['condition1', 'condition2']`

Comment: any elegant suggestion, do I need to create a new column in advance?